azure devops collection settings Rules, how to compare two fields
How to compare two fields in azure devops collection settings rules.
For example when value in field "completed" is more than "original estimate", make mandatory the reason field. Now there is no option provided there to compare two fields.
There is no default settings in drop down list.

In the work item rules, there is not available Condition to compare the values between fields. See "Add a custom rule" and "Rules and rule evaluation". There also are no other built-in options can do this.
If your projects really need this feature, I recommend you try to report a feature request on Developer Community. This will make it more convenient for the engineer teams to receive and understand your ideas. And your feedback also could be helpful for improving the Azure DevOps products.

